# Cron Job Breaks When Reducing AppEngine Traffic Allocation

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

## Expected

Reducing the traffic allocation of a scheduled Cron Job to less than 100% and continuing to have the Cron Job perform it's scheduled task. The Cron Job setup is created to backup data per the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export).

## Observed

The Cron Job appears to not work when reducing AppEngine Traffic Allocation to less than 100%. There are other *Jar* instances running in this AppEngine project that are set to 0% allocation and are running as expected which is why it seems the Cron Job can be set to 0% as well.

[image]

Comment: I'd argue that reducing to 0% is rather equivalent to Stopping than to `Reducing to less than 100%` ;) Do you see the observed 0% working case documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, all of my _Jars_ are running successfully at 0% as indicated above. Perhaps the allocation does not affect the way _Jar_ files are ran.